# Computing a scalar $c$ such that $cx= c(e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{2n})=\omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$.

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $n \geqslant 2$ be an integer and consider the vector space $V=F^{2n}$ with the standard basis $e_1,\ldots,e_{2n}$.

Now the second exterior power $\Lambda^2(V)$ contains the element $$\omega=e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4 + \cdots + e_{2n-1} \wedge e_{2n}.$$

Since $\Lambda^{2n}(V)$ is spanned by $x := e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{2n}$, we know that the $n$-fold wedge product $\omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$ is a scalar multiple of $x$.

> Question: How do we compute this scalar?

Comment: That's only for a $1$-form right? By definition, $v \wedge v = 0$ for every $v \in \Lambda^{1}(V)$. I don't know if it holds for higher powers. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry.

Comment: No worries, there was no harm done.

Comment: The scalar is equal to $n!$, which can be seen by multiplying out and distributing all of the terms above, then noticing that all of the terms with repeated $x_j$ vanish and so you get a sum over permutations in $S_n$. Reordering two at a time doesn't change the sign of the form.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks for the help! If you'd like, feel free to leave your comment as an answer so that this question doesn't remain in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First distribute all terms in the product defining $\omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$ (there are $n$ products). Notice that all of the terms with repeated $x_j$ will vanish by antisymmetricity of the wedge product. Thus you get $$ \omega^{\wedge n} = \sum_{\sigma \in S^*_n} e_{\sigma(1)}\wedge e_{\sigma(1)+1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{\sigma(n)}\wedge e_{\sigma(n)+1}$$

where $S_n^*$ denotes the group of all bijections from $\{1,3,5,...,2n-1\}$ unto itself. Next notice that if $\sigma \in S_n^*$, then $e_{\sigma(1)}\wedge e_{\sigma(1)+1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{\sigma(n)}\wedge e_{\sigma(n)+1} = e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$, because reordering the terms two at a time does not change the sign of the $2n$-form. Consequently, $$\omega^{\wedge n} = \big| S_n^* \big| \cdot e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n = n! \cdot e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$$

Comment: In the last few wedges $e_n$ should be $e_{2n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat more general method that may complement shalop's answer. Let $A_{ij}$ be a matrix of dimension $2n$ and $\widetilde{A}_{ij} = \frac{A_{ij}-A_{ji}}{2}$ be the antisymmetric part. Then let $\omega = \sum_{i,j=1}^{2n} A_{ij} e_i \wedge e_j = \sum_{i,j=1}^{2n} \widetilde{A}_{ij} e_i \wedge e_j$.

Then it is easy to show that $\omega \wedge \dots \wedge \omega = 2^n n! \mathrm{pf}(\widetilde{A}) e_1 \wedge \dots \wedge e_{2n}$ where pf means Pfaffian.

The Pfaffian has the property that $\mathrm{pf}(\widetilde{A})^2 = \det(\widetilde{A})$. In your case $\widetilde{A} =  \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{matrix}\right) \oplus \dots \oplus \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$. From this you have $\mathrm{pf}(\widetilde{A}) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ from which it follows that in your case that $c = 2^n n! \mathrm{pf}(\widetilde{A}) = n!$.